# Multi values for SSRS parameter with Like statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I need to find a way for a multi-value parameter to filter my report where I have a LIKE statement in the query.

I have a parameter that provides me with a list of organs (liver, kidney, heart) where I can select multiple values.  I need to affect two columns (referral_organs and registration_organs).  It is possible to have two organs in the same cell for either referral or registration - for example, there could be a 'liver/kidney' or 'lungs/liver' value in each column.  To deal with this, I used a LIKE statement in my WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (F.REFERRAL_ORGANS LIKE '%' + @ORGAN + '%' OR F.REGISTERED_ORGANS LIKE '%' + @ORGAN + '%')
```

My list of organs comes from another dataset.

This works great for one selected organ but fails on multiple selection.

I have found a fairly close solution here: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162845/multi-values-for-ssrs-parameter-with-like-statement

But this solution states to enter an expression for your dataset instead of a query like this

```
="SELECT "
&     "[NationalIDNumber],"
&      "[JobTitle]"
&"FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]"
&"WHERE [JobTitle] LIKE '%" & Join(Parameters!jobtitle.Label, "%' OR [JobTitle] LIKE '%") & "%'"
```

But I am unclear on how to implement this.

How do I select multiple values for the organ parameter and filter the table with the LIKE statement in my query? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with sql functions?  If so, I would try a table valued function.  See article: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/

From this function, I would do a cross apply to your original data set to get the values you are searching for.  

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but it might... If you provide me a example data set and a result set I might be able to help better.

Comment: Hey thanks.  I will look into table values functions in SSRS. I can't provide an example but I will come back with code if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CHARINDEX to find the REFERRAL_ORGANS in the Join(Parameters!ORGAN.Label, "|").

```
&"WHERE CHARINDEX(F.REFERRAL_ORGANS'" & Join(Parameters!ORGAN.Label, "|") & "') > 0 ...
```

CHARINDEX will return 0 if REFERRAL_ORGANS is **not** found in the concatenated string of the ORGAN  parameter labels so your expression will look for greater than one.

Comment: Hey thanks.  This syntax is unfamiliar to me especially starting with the & and " characters.  Where would I put this code?  My original query is 1000 lines long.

Comment: This was the where clause that you would use in the dataset like the example you gave. In the dataset EXPRESSION, instead of pasting the query, press the Expression button (Fx). In the query Expression, you can build a query from text that will be combined with the SSRS parameter and sent to the server as a query. To convert you query, you can use Notepadd++ and REPLACE **\r\n** with **" & VBCRLF \n & "** (including the double quotes) and add double quotes to the beginning and end of the query. The change the WHERE clause.